# CSS margin-transference bug (ie6 + ie7), would like input

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I am almost done with my project, but have one final looming problem that I'd like some advice on. Info on the CSS "margin transference bug" relating to ie6 and ie7 can be found [here](http://css-class.com/test/bugs/ie/ie-margin-transference-bug.htm) and [here](http://css-class.com/test/bugs/ie/margintransferencebug.htm).

So I have all of these heading tags with `margin-bottom: 24px`. They sit above any number of left-floated divs, depending on the page.

Each of the floated divs sitting below the heading tags "inherit" the heading tags' margin of 24px.

Short of putting EVERY SINGLE heading tag in it's own div, I am out of ideas. Do you have any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Maybe a BETTER question is, "how would you add space below all heading tags without using margin?" Line-height isn't quite cutting it, but what about `padding-bottom`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using background images or background colors behind your headings, I don't see any problem with using padding-bottom.

Comment: After a little more fooling around with it, that's what I'm leaning towards. Anyone advise against it? Not very fond of fudging things like this. Lol